# How to get the sum of a value out of transactions over time

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I have a df showing aprox. 1.600.000 transactions like:

```
start           duration    avg         stop
1.457423e+09    1821.0      0.951126    1.457425e+09
1.457389e+09    35577.0     0.517104    1.457424e+09
1.457425e+09    1232.0      0.000000    1.457425e+09
1.457425e+09    333.0       1.100000    1.457425e+09
1.457425e+09    1.0         0.000000    1.457425e+09
```

Transaction can be overlapping. How can I I get the aggregated sum over time as shown in the lower graph in the picture using Python/Matplotlib

[image]

Comment: If you add some detail to your question describing exactly how your data is overlapping we'll be able to help. It would be clearer to show what you've tried, what output you got and how that differs from what you would like.